# How to let selenium make a random selection on a radion button python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, random

I'm currently working on a project. I want that it chooses a year between 1970 - 1999. The date & month should be randomly chosen. Already tried it per XPath etc. didn't work out very well.

The website is payoneer.com / Login Form date picker

```
birthselection = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id=ui-datepicker-div]/div/div/select[1]/option[5]']").click()
```

Comment: Do you want to pass the random month and date to the xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

// Choose a random number from 0 to 29 and save it under randomNumber element
randomNumber = random.randint(0, 29)

// then I pass the randomNumber value inside the xpath of the option (instead of a static number like 5 or 10, you have to insert dynamically the randomNumber)
birthselection = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id=ui-datepicker-div]/div/div/select[1]/option['+str(randomNumber)+']']").click()
```

At first, you have to import the random package. Then you have to execute the random function (pick a random number from 0 to the limit you want to. To this example is 29 because you have 29 years to pick (insert str() in order to parse your int result into a string).

After the random function returns you value, you have to save this value and insert it inside the XPath you prefer to. If it 15, for example, you will choose the 16th element from your list.

If you need to search for it additionally, you can also check the doc from  here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
import random

randomNumber = random.randint(1970, 1999)

DOB = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id=ui-datepicker-div]/div/div/select[1]/option['+str(randomNumber)+']']").click()
```